# GridView extra header OR merged cells breaks Edit-Update

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header, cells

I need to add an extra header with merged cells to my gridview and it's quite easy to do it.

The problem is as soon a extra header exists in the GridView, the Edit-**Update** doesn't work anymore. **Update** to be precise.  When I press Update, all the columns become empty and the extra-header's rows are gone.

Anyone achieved to add an extra header rows but with a working Update ?

Comment: Do you rebind data in Event RowUpdating or you use SqlDataSource/ObjectDataSource?

Comment: RebindData but columns are all empty

Comment: Could you show your code and screenshot?